# Invoking a Make target in a loop with an argument

Tags: makefile

I am designing a simple makefile that defines one target which takes an argument, and I would like to define a second target that invokes the first target in a loop, once per every variable defined in an array variable at the top of the Makefile.

```
my_loop_var = var1 var2

my_thing:
    echo $MY_VAR
all:
   invoke my_thing once for each value of my_loop_var
```

What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Note: `$MY_VAR` will probably expand as `Y_VAR` because make will try to expand variable `M`, which is probably undefined, and concatenate `Y_VAR` to the result. Use `$(VARNAME)` to expand make variable `VARNAME`. It is only with single-character variable names that you can expand with `$X`.

There is not really a "*right way*". There are many ways. The most straightforward from your specifications (but the less natural) would be something like:

```
my_loop_var := var1 var2

my_thing:
    echo "$(MY_VAR)"

.PHONY: all my_thing

all:
    for v in $(my_loop_var); do $(MAKE) my_thing MY_VAR="$$v"; done
```

The recipe of `all` is a shell loop that re-invokes `make` with the `my_thing` goal and with each value in `my_loop_var` passed as the value of make variable `MY_VAR`.

Note the `$$v` to escape the first expansion that make always performs before passing the recipe to the shell. With just `$v` make would expand the recipe as `... MY_VAR="" ...` and the result would not be what you expect.

Note also the use of the `MAKE` make variable instead of directly calling `make` (have a look at the documentation if you want to understand why it is better like this).

`all` and `my_thing` are declared as phony because they are not real file names that their recipes create, and make needs to know this kind of things.

But a much more make-ish way would be something like:

```
my_loop_var      := var1 var2
my_thing_targets := $(addprefix my_thing_,$(my_loop_var))

.PHONY: all $(my_thing_targets)

all: $(my_thing_targets)

$(my_thing_targets): my_thing_%:
    echo "$*"
```

Here we define as many `my_thing_something` targets as there are `something` values in `my_loop_var`. And explain make how to build such targets with a static pattern rule. In the recipe of a pattern rule the `$*` automatic variable expands as the part that matched the `%` pattern. So, this static pattern rule says that if we need to build `my_thing_something`, the recipe is `echo "something"`.

We declare all these `my_thing_something` targets as prerequisites of `all` such that if you type `make` or `make all`, make will build all the `my_thing_something` targets.

This second solution is better for at least two reasons. First, make is invoked only once, which is better, at least for performance. Second, make can parallelize the build of the `my_thing_something` if you use the `-j N` option (to allow make to run up to `N` jobs in parallel). This also is better for performance.

But it is also a matter of style. Very frequently if you use shell loops in your recipes, especially to invoke make again, it is the sign that you did not really understand what make is intended for and how it works. The make language is not a scripting language (even if the recipes are written in shell language, which is a scripting language); make is designed to "*loop*" over all targets to build, without the need for explicit loops.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. Can you suggest  resources where these concepts about Make are explained so clearly?The Makefile tutorial wasn't that clear, I tried doing the second way myself and couldn't get it working

Comment: @Edmondo1984 The [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is the best resource I know. It is well written and quite comprehensive. When you write "_couldn't get it working_" what do you mean? What didn't work as you expected?

Comment: I wasn't able to use wildcards on my_thing_% :(. It wouldn't match the rule

Comment: I don't understand. If the target of the pattern rule is `my_thing_%` and if you type `make my_thing_var1`, unless you use a make version I never heard about, it should work. What happens if you try to build only one of your `my_thing_something` targets by typing `make my_thing_something`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot an important thing in the second version (I should have tested): it is `$(my_thing_targets): my_thing_%:` (static pattern rule), not `my_thing_%:` (pattern rule). Alternately, do not declare them as phony (but in this case it would be better if they were real files).

Comment: I am a little confused, don't we need to define a rule my_thing_% too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235538/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-edmondo1984).